# Can I skip using docker-compose build --no-cache if I do a docker-compose pull?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Would using docker-compose build --no-cache eliminate the use of docker-compose pull?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but if you want the pull to happen always, then use below

```
docker-compose build --pull --no-cache
```

If you just want a single pull then `docker-compose build` will do auto pull if the image doesn't exists

See the help for same

```
$ docker-compose build --help
Build or rebuild services.

Services are built once and then tagged as `project_service`,
e.g. `composetest_db`. If you change a service's `Dockerfile` or the
contents of its build directory, you can run `docker-compose build` to rebuild it.

Usage: build [options] [--build-arg key=val...] [SERVICE...]

Options:
    --compress              Compress the build context using gzip.
    --force-rm              Always remove intermediate containers.
    --no-cache              Do not use cache when building the image.
    --pull                  Always attempt to pull a newer version of the image.
    -m, --memory MEM        Sets memory limit for the build container.
    --build-arg key=val     Set build-time variables for services.
```